# as.numeric returns completely different value

Tags: r, csv, numeric

converting a data.frame column with as.numeric returns completely different values.
I read in a .csv with

```
data <- read.csv("~/Downloads/data-1.csv")
```

data$column1 returns decimal values I want to work and which look like the following:

[5509] 0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.01  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13  0.13

```
typeof(data$column1)
```

returns "integer"

```
class(data$column1)
```

returns "factor"

But in order to work further with this column I need to convert it into numeric
But

```
as.numeric(data$column1)
```

returns values like these:

[5509]  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14   2  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  14  63  14  14  14  14

Can someone help converting these numbers correctly? Can't figure it out..

Comment: Rather than `as.numeric()` try `as.numeric(as.character(data$column1))`.

Comment: Best place to fix, though, is when you read in the data. Find out why the column is being read as a `factor` (maybe it has non-numeric values somewhere?). You can also use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` so it would at least be a character, or you can explicitly set the column class using the `colClasses` argument of `read.csv`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! as.character did it